# Avoiding equal distances

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory

Is the following consistent?

There exists $X \subseteq [0, 1]$, such that $X$ does not have measure zero and for every $Y \subseteq X$, if $Y$ does not have measure zero, then there are $y_1 < y_2 < y_3 < y_4$  in $Y$ such that $y_2 - y_1 = y_4 - y_3$.

Edit: Under CH, there is no such $X$. This follows from a result of Erdos and Kakutani that says that CH is equivalent to the following statement:

The real line $\mathbb{R}$ can be partitioned into countably many rationally independent sets.

The category analogue has a [positive](http://www.math.huji.ac.il/~akumar/aed.pdf) answer.

Maybe I should add a comment to Pietro Majer's response:

It is a simple consequence of Lebesgue density theorem that every non null measurable $Y$ must contain equal distances. There are non trivial problems about avoiding patterns in positive measure sets ([Erdos similarity problem](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1214571347)) but this one is quite different.

Comment: You ask about consistency (rather than truth or provability). Do you know that the negation is consistent?

Comment: I edited the post to incorporate your query/suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Any measurable $X$ with positive measure does it, e.g. $X:=[0,1]$. Indeed, given any measurable $Y\subset\mathbb{R}$ with positive measure, let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that both $Y_-:=Y\cap (-\infty,a)$ and $Y_+:=Y\cap (a,+\infty)$ have positive measure. By Steinhaus theorem, $Y_--Y_-$ and $Y_+-Y_+$ are nbds of $0$, so in particular there are $y_1<y_2$ in $Y_-$ and $y_3<y_4$ in $Y_+$ as required.

Comment: (not sure if you want to allow non-measurable $Y$'s)

Comment: I do. I know that every positive measure set contains a similar copy of every finite set (Leb. density), The set theory tag was chosen to consider the problem for arbitrary set of reals.